# React.js passing props between separate children via a single parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a front end console that I'm trying to make in react that uses a side menu to filter results from a database that are displayed in a dynamically generated table.

The hierarchy of components is as follows:

```
App.js
|
|--SideMenu.js
|--ResultsTable.js
```

So I understand that the parent has access to props in the child components and that it can also pass props to its children too. What I'm trying to do is to get the sidemenu to speak to the results table via the parent App.js (unless there's a way to get the children to communicate directly?) and update the table accordingly however I've encountered a strange problem. When I click the filter or reset button (in SideMenu.js), there is a delay of props being picked up in the results table component that requires me to click the buttons 2 or 3 times before it registers. I'm sure the solution is simple but so far it has eluded me. I think the problem occurs when App.js is passing the new props back down to ResultTable.js but I'm not entirely sure how to fix it.

Here is my code for the SideMenu.js

```
export default class SideMenu extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state={

            serviceParam: '',
            filterParam: '',
            services: [],
        }

        this.handleServiceChoice = this.handleServiceChoice.bind(this);
        this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
        this.getServices = this.getServices.bind(this);
        this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillMount(){

        this.getServices();
    }

    getServices(){
        const _this =this;
        let servicesData;

        let url = "http://mydevsite.ie/cgi-bin/log-queries/api/services";

        fetch(url)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then(function(data){

                servicesData = data;

                console.log("servicesData");
                console.log(servicesData);

                _this.setState({
                    services: servicesData
                });
            });
    }

    handleReset(){
        this.setState({
            serviceParam: null,
            filterParam: null,
        });

        let dropdownArrow = document.createElement("i");
        dropdownArrow.setAttribute("class", "material-icons right");
        dropdownArrow.innerHTML = "keyboard_arrow_down";
        document.getElementById("serviceDisplay").innerHTML = "Services";
        document.getElementById("serviceDisplay").appendChild(dropdownArrow);

        this.props.filterCallback(this.state.serviceParam);
    }

    handleSearch(){


        if(document.getElementById('search').value && this.state.serviceParam){
            let filterParam = "&search="+document.getElementById('search').value;
            console.log('In child - search 1');
            console.log(filterParam);

            let parentProps;
            parentProps= this.state.serviceParam+filterParam;
            this.props.filterCallback(parentProps);
        } else if (document.getElementById('search').value){
            let filterParam = "?search="+document.getElementById('search').value;
            console.log('In child - search 2');
            console.log(filterParam);

            let parentProps;
            parentProps=filterParam;
            this.props.filterCallback(parentProps);
        } else{
            let filterParam = this.state.serviceParam;
            console.log('In child - search 3');
            console.log(filterParam);

            let parentProps;
            parentProps=filterParam;
            this.props.filterCallback(parentProps);
        }



    }

    handleServiceChoice(e){
        console.log('sidebar target id');
        console.log(e.target.id);

        let serviceParam;
        let dropdownArrow = document.createElement("i");
        dropdownArrow.setAttribute("class", "material-icons right");
        dropdownArrow.innerHTML = "keyboard_arrow_down";
        document.getElementById("serviceDisplay").innerHTML = e.target.id;
        document.getElementById("serviceDisplay").appendChild(dropdownArrow);

        serviceParam = '?service='+e.target.id ;

        this.setState({
            serviceParam: serviceParam,
        });

    }

    render(){
        return(

            <ul className="side-nav fixed blue accent-1">
                <li className="logo"></li>

                <li>
                    <a id="serviceDisplay" href="#" className="dropdown-button waves-effect" data-activates="services">Services<i className="material-icons right">keyboard_arrow_down</i></a>

                        <ul id="services" className="dropdown-content">
                            {this.state.services.map((dropdown)=>{
                                return(
                                    <li key={dropdown.service}>
                                        <a id={dropdown.service} href="#" className="waves-effect" onClick={this.handleServiceChoice}>{dropdown.service}</a>
                                    </li>
                                );
                            })}                 
                        </ul>

                </li>

                <li className="bold"><a href="#">Supplier ID Search</a></li>
                <li className="search">
                    <div className="container center-align">
                        <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Enter ID here" className="validate blue accent-2"></input>

                        <button className="btn blue accent-2 waves-effect" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSearch}>
                            Filter
                            <i className="material-icons right">search</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <div className="container center-align">
                        <button className="btn blue accent-2 waves-effect" type="submit" onClick={this.handleReset}>
                            Reset Logs
                            <i className="material-icons right">autorenew</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </li>


            </ul>
        );



    };
}
```

And the ResultsTable.js:

```
export default class ResultsTable extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            logs: [],
            xml: '',
            render_xml: false,
        }

        this.ResultsTable = this.ResultsTable.bind(this);
        this.handleRequestXML = this.handleRequestXML.bind(this);
        this.handleResponseXML = this.handleResponseXML.bind(this);
        this.returnToLogs = this.returnToLogs.bind(this);
        this.renderTable = this.renderTable.bind(this);
        this.renderXml = this.renderXml.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        console.log('Child - In componentWillMount!');
        this.ResultsTable();

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(){
        console.log('Child - In componentWillReceiveProps!');
        console.log(this.props.filter);

        this.ResultsTable();
    }

    returnToLogs(){
        this.setState({
            render_xml:false
        });
    }

    handleResponseXML(e){
        const _this =this;

        _this.setState({
            render_xml: true,
        });

        let id_param = '?_id='+e.target.id+'&type=response';
        let url = "http://mydevsite.ie/cgi-bin/log-queries/api/xml"+id_param;
        fetch(url)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then(function(data){

                let xml = data;

                console.log("xml");
                console.log(xml);

                _this.setState({
                    xml: xml,
                });

            });
    }

    handleRequestXML(e){
        const _this =this;

        _this.setState({
            render_xml: true,
        });


        let id_param = '?_id='+e.target.id+'&type=request';
        let url = "http://mydevsite.ie/cgi-bin/log-queries/api/xml"+id_param;
        fetch(url)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then(function(data){

                let xml = data;

                console.log("xml");
                console.log(xml);

                _this.setState({
                    xml: xml,
                });
            });
    }

    ResultsTable(){
        console.log('Child - In ResultsTable!');
        console.log(this.props.filter);

        const _this =this;
        let logData;

        let url = "http://mydevsite.ie/cgi-bin/log-queries/api/logs";



        if(this.props.filter){
            console.log('Child - Service Choice!');
            console.log(this.props.filter);
            url +=this.props.filter;
        }

        fetch(url)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then(function(data){

                logData = data;

                console.log("logData");
                console.log(logData);

                _this.setState({
                    logs: logData
                });
            });

    }



    renderTable(){
        console.log('In renderTable!');
        return (

            <table className="highlight">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Created</th>
                        <th>Last Changed</th>
                        <th>Service</th>
                        <th>Supplier Identifier</th>
                        <th>Request XML</th>
                        <th>Response XML</th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.logs.map((log)=>{
                    return(
                        <tr key={log._id}>
                            <td>{log._id}</td>
                            <td>{log.created}</td>
                            <td>{log.last_changed}</td>
                            <td>{log.service}</td>
                            <td>{log.supplier_identifier}</td>
                            <td><a id={log._id} onClick={this.handleRequestXML} href='#'>Click for XML</a></td>
                            <td><a id={log._id} onClick={this.handleResponseXML} href='#'>Click for XML</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                })}

                </tbody>


            </table>


        );
    }

    renderXml(){
        console.log("In renderXml");
        return(
            <div className="card-panel">
                {this.state.xml}
                <hr/>
                <a className="waves-effect btn blue accent-2" onClick={this.returnToLogs}>Back to logs</a>
            </div>

        );
    }

    render(){
        if(this.state.render_xml){
            return this.renderXml();
        } else {
            return this.renderTable();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the parent App.js component

```
export default class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            filter: null,
        }

        this.handleFilterParam = this.handleFilterParam.bind(this);
    }

    handleFilterParam(filter){
        console.log('In parent - handleSearchParam');
        console.log(filter);
        this.setState({
            filter: filter
        });
    }

    render(){
        console.log('In parent - render');
        console.log(this.state.filter);

        return (
            <div className="row">

                <div className="col s4 l3">
                    <SideMenu 
                        filterCallback={this.handleFilterParam}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col s12 l9">
                    <Header />
                    <ResultsTable filter={this.state.filter}/>
                </div>

            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

I'm still quite new to React and ES6 so apologies in advance if some of this seems quite amateurish.

Comment: Just pass down some callback as props to the component, which will execute the code in App component and then rerender the other.

Comment: @Angels I believe that is what he is doing already. OP, I see you are using `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the results based on the filter changing, but I would assume you need to use `componentWillUpdate`, which will receive the new props. Now, whenever a filter changes, you are doing your api calls with the old props

Comment: @Angels I'm pretty sure that's what I'm doing at the minute. I have a callback in the SideMenu that then triggers the App.js to pass the new prop back down to the ResultsTable, but it doesn't seem to be picking it up and rerendering upon the first button click. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Sander I'm still getting my head around the lifecycle functions of react but Ill try switching to componentWillUpdate and see if that makes a difference. If I recall, I might have had that function at one point and it was firing off every couple of seconds for some reason but I'll see how it goes.

Comment: this.props.filterCallback(this.state.serviceParam); it won't pass null to the App, the state hasn't updated yet, just pass null expicitly.

Comment: Passing null explicitly seems to help the reset button. There still seems to be some kind of delay happening, however the componentWillUpdate is doing what I thought it would do; its being triggered every second or so - which alleviates the problem but seems like a hack. Is that function supposed to operate this way?

Comment: It should trigger only once per your filter update or reset. Don't name class functions the same as your class, it's dangerous. Also, don't bind every function you got, only those you'll need to be binded.

Comment: @Angels Ok, I've renamed that function so its not the same as the class however the `componentWillUpdate` is still being triggered every second or so. Could there possibly be something else in another component causing this?

Comment: You don't need componentWillUpdate. Every time you fetch your data from server, you updating the state, then this method triggers and you are fetching your data again and again. Yes, it will.

Comment: @Angels Ok cool I'll try that and see if it stops the constant triggering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148420/discussion-between-angels-and-mark-ohare).

Comment: @Angels It seems now that the table won't update at all now. The api is called within ResultsTable so it has to know that its received new props in order to update the table. Im pretty sure I'm passing the prop correctly in App.js as far as I know. How can I make sure that ResultsTable updates correctly when receiving it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty simply solution to my problem in case anyone is wondering and viewing this question. I was using this lifecycle method before but didn't quite understand it until now.

So, in my ResultsTable component, I added this code to 'listen' for new props and update accordingly:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(this.props != nextProps) {
            this.props = nextProps;
            this.handleResultsTable();
        }
    }
```